# SimCenter constraints for a block on a surface and on a shaft

Tags: simulation, finite-element-analysis, siemens, siemens-nx

I have a block, pictured below. Its use case is that it is sitting on a surface (~frictionless) and has a static rigid shaft through it (also ~frictionless). Loads are applied on the top and bottom and I want to see how it deforms around the shaft. For the bottom surface, I have applied a Simply Supported constraint. For the hole through which the shaft goes, I'm really not sure how to do that. Everything I've tried has given me an 'Active BC Conflict' error. Guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Some more specific notes:

- It can't be a rigid constraint because then it would resist the top load
- Ideally, the constraint applies in such a way that the theoretical shaft can only push on the material, but not pull. This means that force on the inside surface of the block hole has to always be 0 or be in compression. If this isn't possible, I'll live, but it would be more accurate if I could make this work.

[image: the block I have modeled and need to simulate]